# running guard throwing error

Tags: rspec, guard

Guard giving error on windows 7(64-bit)

Hi Community members, I am new to ruby and I am trying to learn rspec and in process of running rspec example using guard.

I am trying to run a simple rspec example (by setting following environment) before issuing command
guard to watch for the rspec resources

```
ruby-1.9.3p545
rspec-3.0.0
guard-2.6.2
guard-rspec-4.2.9
```

Log:

```
C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/adapter/windows.rb:21:in `rescue in usable?': undefined method `_log' for Listen::Adapter::Windows:Class (NoMethodError)
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/adapter/windows.rb:17:in `usable?'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:32:in `each'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listn/adapter.rb:32:in `detect'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:32:in `_usable_adapter_class'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/adapter.rb:20:in `select'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:252:in `_adapter_class'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:208:in `_init_actors'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:72:in `block in <class:Listener>'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/fsm.rb:175:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/fsm.rb:175:in `call'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/fsm.rb:127:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/fsm.rb:95:in `transition'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:85:in `start'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:30:in `block in start'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:108:in `block in within_preserved_state'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:105:in `within_preserved_state'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:26:in `start'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:107:in `start'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.6.1/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `load'
    from C:/softwares/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.
I would greatly appreciate your help.

NB

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same problem.

It looks like it might be an issue with listen version 2.7.6, which was released today. Try manually installing listen 2.6.5:

If you're using bundler:

```
gem 'listen', '2.7.5'
```

If you installed using rubygems:

```
gem uninstall listen
gem install listen -v 2.7.5
```

EDIT: for any googlers, version 2.7.9 is now out, making this answer out of date.

Comment: Thank you Zishe. Doing above thing gem uninstall listen gem install listen -v 2.7.5 is no longer giving me the error related to listen but I am getting following message  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
  require 'rbconfig'
  if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/i
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0'
  end

Comment: If I have installed using rubygems <br/> where do i need to configure this

Comment: @NBB, if you're not using bundler, type `gem install wdm`

Comment: canton7 I tried installing wdm and I am getting following error <br/>C:\bdd\demo3>gem install wdm
Fetching: wdm-0.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing wdm:
        The 'wdm' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Comment: @NBB And did you follow the instructions at the link which *you posted*?

Comment: I followed the instructions to install devkit and did not get any errors.But now though it displays the message C:\bdd\demo3>guard
10:27:23 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
10:27:23 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
10:27:23 - INFO - Guard is now watching at 'C:/bdd/demo3' <br/> when I make a change to my class file in ruby , guard doesn't pick the changes. According to tutorial I am following, I should see  [1] guard main after INFO - Guard is now watching at 'C:/bdd/demo3' which I am not

Comment: @NBB, at this point we've strayed into an entirely different question (and it sounds like your tutorial is wrong). If this answer answered the question which you asked, please mark it as the accepted answer. If you still have (different) questions, please ask them as separate questions.

Comment: Thanks @canton7. Its no longer giving the error now.